# Changing Cursor

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to change the mouse cursor -while in running the program only- the OS is windows.
I have tried this

```
const char * s = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PT_Project\cur1.ani";
HCURSOR Cursor = LoadCursorFromFile(s);
HCURSOR WINAPI SetCursor(Cursor);
```

but it's didn't work despite me doing everything to the file path.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How the hell does `HCURSOR WINAPI SetCursor(Cursor);` compile? That looks like a broken function declaration, not a function call.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Is `LoadCursorFromFile()` returning NULL? If so, call `GetLastError()` to find out why, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648392.aspx). Please provide a [mcve] showing exactly what you are doing. When and where in your code are you calling `LoadCursorFromFile()` and `SetCursor()`?

Comment: @Quentin I saw it on MSDN overe here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AhmedKh yes, that's the function's declaration. You need to call it, so drop the `HCURSOR WINAPI` -- just like you did with `LoadCursorFromFile`.

Comment: @Quentin Now its working, only the new cursor disappears almost instantly, why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond to the [`WM_SETCURSOR` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382(v=vs.85).aspx). If you don't, the default processing will return the cursor that is registered to the window class. This message comes quite often, in response to a mouse move for example.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what you mean, I am not getting any messages

Comment: @AhmedKh if you don't have a message handler then you will never be able to change your cursor.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `SetCursor()` sets the cursor globally, so technically it is possible to change the screen cursor without processing any UI messages at all.  In response to `WM_SETCURSOR` is the *preferred* way to go, but it is not the only way. The real question is, if the app is "not getting any messages", then when and how is the app trying to set the cursor at all?  Is it at app startup?  In reply to something other than a UI message?

Comment: @RemyLebeau the SetCursor function is in the constructor of a class, and I am not famillar with WM_SETCURSOR at all sadly

Comment: @RemyLebeau sure you can call `SetCursor` any time you'd like. But as soon as some window responds to `WM_SETCURSOR` it will change it back again, making it appear as if the `SetCursor` didn't work.

Comment: @MarkRansom so how do I make it work using the WM_SETCURSOR ?

Comment: @AhmedKh in your message map or message processing loop, put a check for `WM_SETCURSOR`. When you get it, call `SetCursor` and return `TRUE`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ahh now, It's working but the cursor changes almost instantly.. I don't know what do you mean with messape map.. I am pretty new with Windows.h library and sorry for the late reply

Comment: @MarkRansom I have read some stuff about `WM_SETCURSOR`I think I have found a scenario where it would work as I plan but I need to know the right function for it   `case WM_SETCURSOR: 
 
    // If the window is minimized, draw the hCurs3 cursor. 
    // If the window is not minimized, draw the default 
    // cursor (class cursor). 
 
    if (IsIconic(hwnd)) //Replace this line with something that returns true as long as the program is running
    { 
        SetCursor(Cursor); 
        break; 
    } 
`  If this code is correct, should it be implemented as is, in the program start?

Comment: @AhmedKh if you're new to Windows and don't understand what I'm telling you, you need to take a course or tutorial. It's pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes.

```
const char * s = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\PT_Project\\cur1.ani";
```